# add a stopwatch to a game in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i want to add a stopwatch in my pygame. I am planning to modify this code and add in my pygame:

```
Sec += 1
print(str(Min) + " Mins " + str(Sec) + " Sec ")
if Sec == 60:
    Sec = 0
    Min += 1
    print(str(Min) + " Minute")
```

Should i add a timer box in my def **init** part and create a new def for the timer code? I want to have the timer without using the code tick since my game is running clock.tick(60) so it does not effect the tick

*UPDATED*
So here is my game code:

```
import sys, pygame, random

class Breakout():

def main(self):

    xspeed_init = 6
    yspeed_init = 6
    max_lives = 5
    bat_speed = 30
    score = 0 
    bgcolour = 0x2F, 0x4F, 0x4F  # darkslategrey        
    size = width, height = 640, 480

    pygame.init()            
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    #screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.FULLSCREEN)

    bat = pygame.image.load("bat.png").convert()
    batrect = bat.get_rect()

    ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert()
    ball.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
    ballrect = ball.get_rect()

    pong = pygame.mixer.Sound('Blip_1-Surround-147.wav')
    pong.set_volume(10)        

    wall = Wall()
    wall.build_wall(width)

    # Initialise ready for game loop
    batrect = batrect.move((width / 2) - (batrect.right / 2), height - 20)
    ballrect = ballrect.move(width / 2, height / 2)       
    xspeed = xspeed_init
    yspeed = yspeed_init
    lives = max_lives
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1,30)       
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)       # turn off mouse pointer

    while 1:

        # 60 frames per second
        clock.tick(60)

        # process key presses
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit()
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:                        
                    batrect = batrect.move(-bat_speed, 0)     
                    if (batrect.left < 0):                           
                        batrect.left = 0      
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:                    
                    batrect = batrect.move(bat_speed, 0)
                    if (batrect.right > width):                            
                        batrect.right = width

        # check if bat has hit ball    
        if ballrect.bottom >= batrect.top and \
           ballrect.bottom <= batrect.bottom and \
           ballrect.right >= batrect.left and \
           ballrect.left <= batrect.right:
            yspeed = -yspeed                
            pong.play(0)                
            offset = ballrect.center[0] - batrect.center[0]                          
            # offset > 0 means ball has hit RHS of bat                   
            # vary angle of ball depending on where ball hits bat                      
            if offset > 0:
                if offset > 30:  
                    xspeed = 7
                elif offset > 23:                 
                    xspeed = 6
                elif offset > 17:
                    xspeed = 5 
            else:  
                if offset < -30:                             
                    xspeed = -7
                elif offset < -23:
                    xspeed = -6
                elif xspeed < -17:
                    xspeed = -5     

        # move bat/ball
        ballrect = ballrect.move(xspeed, yspeed)
        if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
            xspeed = -xspeed                
            pong.play(0)            
        if ballrect.top < 0:
            yspeed = -yspeed                
            pong.play(0)               

        # check if ball has gone past bat - lose a life
        if ballrect.top > height:
            lives -= 1
            # start a new ball
            xspeed = xspeed_init
            rand = random.random()                
            if random.random() > 0.5:
                xspeed = -xspeed 
            yspeed = yspeed_init            
            ballrect.center = width * random.random(), height / 3                                
            if lives == 0:                    
                msg = pygame.font.Font(None,70).render("Game Over", True, (0,255,255), bgcolour)
                msgrect = msg.get_rect()
                msgrect = msgrect.move(width / 2 - (msgrect.center[0]), height / 3)
                screen.blit(msg, msgrect)
                pygame.display.flip()
                # process key presses
                #     - ESC to quit
                #     - any other key to restart game
                while 1:
                    restart = False
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            sys.exit()
                        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                                sys.exit()
                            if not (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):                                    
                                restart = True      
                    if restart:                   
                        screen.fill(bgcolour)
                        wall.build_wall(width)
                        lives = max_lives
                        score = 0
                        break

        if xspeed < 0 and ballrect.left < 0:
            xspeed = -xspeed                                
            pong.play(0)

        if xspeed > 0 and ballrect.right > width:
            xspeed = -xspeed                               
            pong.play(0)

        # check if ball has hit wall
        # if yes yhen delete brick and change ball direction
        index = ballrect.collidelist(wall.brickrect)       
        if index != -1: 
            if ballrect.center[0] > wall.brickrect[index].right or \
               ballrect.center[0] < wall.brickrect[index].left:
                xspeed = -xspeed
            else:
                yspeed = -yspeed                
            pong.play(0)              
            wall.brickrect[index:index + 1] = []
            score += 10

        screen.fill(bgcolour)
        scoretext = pygame.font.Font(None,40).render(str(score), True, (0,255,255), bgcolour)
        scoretextrect = scoretext.get_rect()
        scoretextrect = scoretextrect.move(width - scoretextrect.right, 0)
        screen.blit(scoretext, scoretextrect)

        for i in range(0, len(wall.brickrect)):
            screen.blit(wall.brick, wall.brickrect[i])    

        # if wall completely gone then rebuild it
        if wall.brickrect == []:              
            wall.build_wall(width)                
            xspeed = xspeed_init
            yspeed = yspeed_init                
            ballrect.center = width / 2, height / 3

        screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
        screen.blit(bat, batrect)
        pygame.display.flip()

class Wall():

    def __init__(self):
        self.brick = pygame.image.load("brick.png").convert()
        brickrect = self.brick.get_rect()
        self.bricklength = brickrect.right - brickrect.left       
        self.brickheight = brickrect.bottom - brickrect.top             

    def build_wall(self, width):        
        xpos = 0
        ypos = 60
        adj = 0
        self.brickrect = []
        for i in range (0, 52):           
            if xpos > width:
                if adj == 0:
                    adj = self.bricklength / 2
                else:
                    adj = 0
                xpos = -adj
                ypos += self.brickheight

        self.brickrect.append(self.brick.get_rect())    
        self.brickrect[i] = self.brickrect[i].move(xpos, ypos)
        xpos = xpos + self.bricklength

if __name__ == '__main__':
    br = Breakout()
    br.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to get the number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` was called, and then use simple division to get the seconds and minutes etc from that number.

Here's a simple example:

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    font=pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 34)
    font.origin=True
    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT: return
        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey12'))
        ticks=pygame.time.get_ticks()
        millis=ticks%1000
        seconds=int(ticks/1000 % 60)
        minutes=int(ticks/60000 % 24)
        out='{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}:{millis}'.format(minutes=minutes, millis=millis, seconds=seconds)
        font.render_to(screen, (100, 100), out, pygame.Color('dodgerblue'))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

[image]

If you want to have your stopwatch "to start later", you could store the output of `pygame.time.get_ticks()` at this moment and simply substract it from the result of further calls (something like `starttime=pygame.time.get_ticks()` and `ticks=pygame.time.get_ticks()-starttime` later in the loop, you'll get the idea).

Comment: so where should i add this code to my game so the timer will also display on the game?

Comment: The easiest way would be to just put the relevant code into your main loop. Maybe create a simple function for it and call it in your main loop.

Answer (score 0):

If your game is running on while loop, with fps of 60, you can get minutes and seconds by doing so:

```
frame_count = 0
frame_rate = 60

... while block of game running 60 fps

    # Every second passes 60 frames, so you get seconds by dividing
    # by 60
    seconds = total_seconds // 60

    # Because 1 second is 60 frames, minute is 60 seconds * 60 frames.
    # So you divide by 60 * 60 = 3600 
    minutes = total_seconds // 3600  # Because every second is 60 fps 

    output_string = "Time: {0:02}:{1:02}".format(minutes, seconds)

    frame_count += 1
```

I found this solution [here](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/f.php?file=timer.py)

Comment: but my game is running clock.tick(60), if i use the above code it will mess up my game speed. Is it possible to make a stopwatch without using tick?

Comment: You don't have to use clock.tick, but you need frame_rate when you render your game.